# situation when Monte Carlo method cannot be used

Tags: integration, expectation, monte-carlo, variance

This is an example from notes
[image]

I don't understand why we should think about the $E(x)$ and $var(x)$ first?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1$, it's a probability density.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your answer, yeah, it is 1, stupid me. But why we need to consider E(x) and its variance first?

Comment: Well...what else would you consider?  You are right, in that the divergence of the core integral would have made sampling pointless.  But the integral is just fine, so you can't argue that way.  Infinite mean and variance, though, means that sampling will be entirely useless and chaotic.

Comment: As a suggestion...try it.  Nothing goes wrong with the implementation.  Take a look at the values you get.  You are probably used to integrands that decay a lot faster at Infinity.

Comment: @lulu if I implement it by running simulation, yes, the value would be $\infty$, but I still don't understand why it is because E(x) is $\infty$ that caused the problem

Comment: If you expect a sampled value to be $≥M$ for all $M$, then of course the integral should be enormous.

Answer (score 1):

**Longer than a comment and may be late for this question, but essentially a comment :)**

This comment may be of little use any longer, but consider splitting the integral as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}f(x)dx+\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^1f(x)dx+\int_1^{\infty}f(x)dx,$$ change variables $u=\frac{1}{x}$ in the first and last integrals to get
$$\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}dx+\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^1f(x)dx+\int_0^1\frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}dx,$$
or simply
$$
\int_{-1}^1f(x)+\frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}dx.
$$
Now, Monte Carlo integration is applicable as ever. Numerical simulations yield
$$
{
n=10^4\implies I=0.9863872988267333,
\\
n=10^5\implies I=1.0010829777555326,
\\
n=10^6\implies I=0.998729665417855,
\\
n=10^7\implies I=1.0002986899268542,
}
$$
which are quite close to the *theoretical* integral value $1$.